# MobileFirst Server log file size in production

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

**Questions:**

1) Is it a common practice to limit the log file size of MobileFirst Server in production? The log in this folder will keep on increasing (I expect this log will actually affect the server performance and the server will crash after a stress test to the server)

2) If yes, how to set it? Is it in /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/mfp/server.xml?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It is common to customize the log file sizes and the location on production.

You can set the log file size on Liberty by using the attribute: `maxFileSize` in server.xml  -  */opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/mfp/server.xml* .

The attribute `maxFiles` sets the number of files of each type that are kept on the file system.

Another useful one would be to set the **environment variable** `LOG_DIR` - You could possibly set it to a different mount point.

You can find more details on this from this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html)

Comment: what's the purpose of setting this? com.ibm.ws.logging.message.file.name=loggingMessages.log

Comment: com.ibm.ws.logging.message.file.name is used to change the name of the message log file. By default the file name is messages.log. You can change it to a different name either using `com.ibm.ws.logging.message.file.name=loggingMessages.log`  in bootstrap.properties file or equivalently, use the attribute `messageFileName` in server.xml.